# nutch crawler: db_unfetched a large number and no fetching is done

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I am using nutch to crawl and download content from wikipedia from a certain domain. In the log I see that around 3000 urls are fetched But when I look at the stats, db_fetched is just 81 while db_unfetched is ~2900.
In the log no exception occurs while downloading but somehow the urls are not downloaded to my computer. I have set the topN to 50000 and depth to 50.